# Custom alert dialog in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, alert

I'm trying to create a custom alert dialog with an image background and some custom styling, but can't seem to find out how to do this using Alert or AlertIOS in react-native. Is this possible, or is there some library that can help me out?

Answer (score 23):

Both `Alert` and `AlertIOS` utilise each platform's native simple alert dialog. On iOS the underlying native component is simplistic and only accepts a title, message, and buttons, with a similar case on Android.

For a more custom approach you could use [React Native Modalbox](https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox), or [React Native Modal](https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-modal) - both of which provide a highly-customisable modal component.

In future I'd recommend using [JS.coach](https://js.coach/) for a comprehensive list of quality React Native components.