# React-Native custom dialog

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, dialog

I am using React-Native to create my project, in my project I need a dialog.

[image]

How can I make the dialog just like the image? If anyone have an example about it please tell me **its very important in my App thank you**. 
I also tried this from React-Native documentation but I can't modify it to be like this photo.

I tried many examples in the internet but I failed to make it.

```
Alert.alert(
  'Alert Title',
  'My Alert Msg',
    [
      {text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
      {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
      {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
    ]
)
```

Comment: try the solution given in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37540371/1868008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Alert` is a pretty good component if you just want to display a simple message using the system-default layout for modal messages. Otherwise, I'd recommend using the [`Modal`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html) component. The documentation example is pretty good to help you understand how to customize it to fit your particular usecase.

Comment: thank you , but do you have any example to help me ?

Comment: Have a look at the example in the documentation, make it run and get familiar with the different functionality. If you still need help afterwards, let me know and I will try to make a toy example.

Comment: i tried the example and its ok,but i move to another screen to show it , i dont need to move , i just open it like popup !

Comment: The `animationType` property lets you specify the animation of the modal. The example does not move to a different screen, it just overlays the modal atop the current view. I think that should be what you want.

Comment: ok , now i have another problem , please check it if you have any idea ! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806590/use-two-constructors-in-react-native