# use two constructors in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

i have a project in react-native , in my project i have list view and modal , list view need constructor , and modal need constructor when i tried to use two constructors i got error , how i can solve this case ? please help !!

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';  
import {  
    StyleSheet,
    ToolbarAndroid
    ,AppRegistry,
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Modal,
    TextInput,
    ListView,ActionButton,
    Image,
    Alert
} from 'react-native';
var DialogAndroid = require('react-native-dialogs');

export default class HygexListView extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.state = {
            visible: false
        };
    }
 constructor(props){

    super(props);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 != r2
    });
    this.state = {
      ds:[{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"},{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"},{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"},{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"},{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"},{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"},{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"},{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"},{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"}],
      dataSource:ds,
    }


  }



  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
      dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.ds),
    })

  }
  pressRow(rowData){

    var newDs = [];
    newDs = this.state.ds;
    newDs[0].Selection = newDs[0] == "CustomerName" ? "CustomerPhone" : "";
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newDs)
    })

    showModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            visible: true
        });
    };

    hideModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            visible: false
        });
    };

  }

  renderRow(rowData){
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={()=> this.showModal()}
        underlayColor = '#ddd'>
        <View style ={styles.row}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:19}}>{rowData.CustomerName} {"\n"} {rowData.CustomerPhone} </Text>
          <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <Text style={styles.selectionText}>{rowData[rowData.Selection]}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>

    )
  } 
   render() {
  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.toolbar}>
  <TouchableHighlight >
  <Image style={styles.imagestyle}
  source={require('./ic_search.png')}/>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  <Text style={styles.toolbarTitle}>CUSTOMERS</Text>
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.moveToAddNewCustomer()}>
  <Image style={styles.imagestyle}
  source={require('./ic_action_name.png')} />
    </TouchableHighlight>

    </View>



  <ListView
        dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow = {this.renderRow.bind(this)}>
      </ListView>
        <View style={styles.x}>
                    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.action1}>
                   <Text style={styles.actionText}>CUSTOMERS</Text>
                   </TouchableHighlight>
                     <TouchableHighlight style={styles.action1}
                    onPress={() => this.moveToOrderEntry()}>
                    <Text style={styles.actionText}>Order Entry</Text>
                   </TouchableHighlight>

                   <TouchableHighlight style={styles.action}
                    onPress={() => this.moveToMyOredre()}>
                    <Text style={styles.actionTex1}>My Order</Text>
                   </TouchableHighlight>

                         </View>
                           <Modal
                visible={this.state.visible}
            >

<View style={styles.modalContainer}>
 <View style={styles.toolbar}>
   <View>
<Text style={styles.toolbarTitle}>X</Text>
</View>
<Text style={styles.toolbarTitle}>Details</Text>
                      </View>
                      <View style={styles.ButtonflexDirection}>
    <Text >CUSTOMER Name</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.ButtonflexDirection}>
    <Text >Address</Text>

    </View>
    <View style={styles.ButtonflexDirection}>
    <Text >Phone Number</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.ButtonflexDirection}>
    <Text >Interested Product</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.ButtonflexDirection}>
    <Text >Discount</Text>
    </View>
    <View >
 <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                    onPress={() => this.moveToHygexListView()}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>           ADD ORDER</Text>

                  </TouchableHighlight>
                      </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>

      </View>
        )
    }
      moveToMyOredre() {
      this.props.navigator.push({
        id: 'MyOrder'
      })
 }
     moveToOrderEntry() {
      this.props.navigator.push({
        id: 'OrderEntry'
      })
 }
       moveToAddNewCustomer() {
      this.props.navigator.push({
        id: 'AddNewCustomer'
      })
 }

}
```

Comment: There is no polymorphism of that sort in ES6, and your instance will always receive the `props` value in the arguments, even if you do not write any parameters in the function declaration, hence, you cannot have two constructors. You say that the view and the modal need a constructor. What does that exactly mean?

Comment: this is my code check it , when i run the code i got error , "duplicate use constructor" !! how to solve it ?

Comment: You cannot have two constructors. Merge the logic of both into one and it should work.

Comment: how to make it ? can you Merge it ? my code is here !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just one constructor:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 != r2
  });
   this.state = {
     ds:[{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"},{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"},{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"},{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"},{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"},{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"},{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"},{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"},{CustomerName: "Customer Name", CustomerPhone: "+564659878964"}],
     dataSource:ds,
     visible: false,
    }


}
```