# how do I style an Alert element in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working with react-native and I have created an Alert element.

```
Alert.alert(
    'Warning',
    'bla bla bla',
    [
           {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
    ]
)
```

Now I'd like to apply some style to it. Let's say I want to apply to it a red background color and white color for the text.

How can I achieve this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a custom library like [react-native-modalbox](https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox).

You'll be able to style the modal as you like:

```
        <Modal style={{background: 'red'}} ref={"modal1"}>
          <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Basic modal</Text>
          <Button onPress={this.toggleSwipeToClose} style={styles.btn}>Disable swipeToClose({this.state.swipeToClose ? "true" : "false"})</Button>
        </Modal>
```

You can open the modal using

```
openModal1(id) {
    this.refs.modal1.open();
  }
```

Check out [the example](https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox/blob/master/Example/index.ios.js) to see more options.

**Bonus**: If you want to find a good library for react-native, try [js.coach](https://js.coach/react-native)

Comment: how i can define common modal like this, and use everywhere

Comment: Modal is not alert.

Comment: Modal is not alert, but the answer is accepted? Strange.

Answer (score 22):

There actually is a way to customize the text on the buttons but you're limited to what is provided... Below is the type definition from react native. Then a simple example showing a red button. Basically the "default" is blue, "cancel" is bold but still blue and "destructive" is red.

```
**
 * An Alert button style
*/
export type AlertButtonStyle = $Enum<{
/**
* Default button style
*/
'default': string,
/**
* Cancel button style
*/
'cancel': string,
/**
* Destructive button style
*/
'destructive': string,
}>;


Alert.alert("Look out!",
        "Hitting reset will wipe all the app's data on your phone. This cannot be undone!",
        [
        {text: 'Reset', onPress: this._doSomethingSerious, style: 'destructive'},
        {text: 'Cancel'},
        ],
        {cancelable: false}
    )
```

Comment: I think this works only for iOS, as specified in the [RN docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert#ios)

Comment: style: 'destructive' is what I need to change cancel button color as red.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is possible, because the `Alert` component of react-native is something included in Android and iOS and cannot be modified :/

I recommend this kind of similar probleme [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535263/custom-alert-dialog-in-react-native) !

See ya !

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for this in android/rn sources.

Looking at [the implementation](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/14c03298d851b1b36854eda994ff62a8406bff56/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/dialog/AlertFragment.java#L46) code, it instantiates an `AlertDialog.Builder`, and looking at the android original [source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/41b4b849fc1a60e577d9ba617c86d3e45aab5297/core/java/android/app/AlertDialog.java#L211-L228) for the `AlertDialog.Builder`, the constructor with only context uses a `resolveDialogTheme` with `themeResId=0`. Anyway, the important part about this method is this:

```java
} else {
   final TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
   context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.alertDialogTheme, outValue, true);
   return outValue.resourceId;
}
```

The fallback style/theme is `alertDialogTheme`, so you can override the alert dialog default theme with `android:alertDialogTheme` like this:

```xml
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeAlert</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeAlert" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <!-- This one changes buttons text color -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#152849</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I needed to change the text for default buttons, so this worked for me (at least on RN 0.61.5), but I'm not sure about which props could be changed.

Of course, this doesn't solve changing colors at runtime... if that's really needed you probably should use a lib or write a native module yourself.

Comment: One minor change though, it's `colorPrimary` and not `colorAccent`