# How do I style an alert in react native

Tags: react-native

how do i change the color and center the text of my alert box in react native.

Here is my code.

```
 Alert.alert(
  'Edit Profile',
  'User Save Succesful!',
  [
    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
  ],
  { cancelable: false }
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I style an Alert element in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665902/how-do-i-style-an-alert-element-in-react-native)