# How to change Alert button color in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

In Native `Android`, we can change the button color in `Alert Dialog` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965662/how-can-i-change-default-dialog-button-text-color-in-android-5).

How to perform similar styling for `Alert` in `React Native`?

Here is my code for `Alert`:

```
Alert.alert(
    'Alert Title',
    'Alert Message / Description?',
    [
        { text: 'No', onPress: () => this.actionNo() },
        { text: 'Yes', onPress: () => this.actionYes() }
    ],
    { cancelable: false }
);
```

Note: **This is not duplicate.** Here I've asked about how to use `Alert` dialog styling, without changing the implementation to `Model`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I style an Alert element in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665902/how-do-i-style-an-alert-element-in-react-native)

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted.

Answer (score 13):

I was going through the same thing and I found a way to style it.
in styles.xml add:

In  AppTheme add:

```
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
```

Then:

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">#00397F</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#00397F</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#0AAEEF</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#F0A90F</item>
</style>

<style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#F0A90F</item>
</style>
```

Play with it and add more customized values as needed.