# how to change the color of Alert box button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

how can I change the color of button text inside alert box in react native.

```
 Alert.alert('Hey There!', 'This is an Alert');
```

Above line generates a simple alert dialog with single "OK" button. I want to change "OK" button color which is default by blue color in android how can I change it to dark gray.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665902/how-do-i-style-an-alert-element-in-react-native) helps you?

Answer (score 0):

The alert box is part of the system, so you can't change it with CSS. Every operating system will have its own alert box appearance.

If you want to influence the appearance of an alert box, you will have to manually create your own as an HTML element, and create your own javascript function which mimics the built-in alert.

If you're able to use jQuery, you could look into the [dialog()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_dialog.htm) function, for example.