How to show os styled alert on android in react native?
So, when I use react-native Alert.alert() function on Android, it shows a default-styled android alert. I want an alert styled depending on device manufacturer, such as OneUI on Samsung (examples: 1 and 2 with Samsung Developer API). Is this possible with react-native?
My example code:
import {Alert, Button} from "react-native";

export default function Test() {
    return (
        <>
            <Button title={'show alert'} onPress={() => {
                Alert.alert("Hello", "This is three option alert.", [
                    {
                        text: "May be",
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Yes",
                    },
                    {
                        text: "No",
                    },
                ])
            }}/>
        </>
    )
}

I tried asking gpt and searching the solution on the Google, but no result.

Does this answer your question? how do I style an Alert element in react-native?

@user18309290 No, because I don't want to change the default alert style, in my case I want it to be dependent on the Android phone manufacturer like Samsung with OneUI.

In Android, React native Alert is calling features from com.facebook.react.modules.dialog, it is a custom dialog and not related to Android's AlertDialog.
So if you want to use native AlertDialog, please choose neither of the options:

Writing your own NativeModule, create a method with AlertDialog creation code: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#export-a-native-method-to-javascript

Try custom the theme react native Alert (android:alertDialogTheme) using theme of android:Theme.Dialog.Alert, these links may help you to do so:
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/themes
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59725096/15847234



I tried creating my NativeModule in android/ folder but it shows a default android alert.

here's my test application repo

Hmm, the font seem right, but it not have the circular border... Can you make sure that your device is running OneUI 5 or 6? And please maybe try adding androidx.compose.material3:material3 to your app/build.gradle?

the buttons are totally different, and I am running test app on my physical device with OneUI 6

tried adding material3 to my app, still didn't work

please help, I don't understand

Hi, if even android native cannot show the right UI, then that have to be something from native, please check your side about it.
My Samsung tablet showing the right UI btw

maybe it's because I'm using expo? send screenshot please how it works on your side

and send your material3 code if you can, thanks
