# How do i change the color of my alert in react native

Tags: react-native

How do i change the background color, font size of my alert box in react native? I put my alert after a button is clicked. I don't know how to style this one, Thanks for the help

```
Alert.alert(
  'Plate',
  'Plate has been sent for printing!',
  [
    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
  ],
  { cancelable: false }
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom alert dialog in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535263/custom-alert-dialog-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`
2. Add `<item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>` inside `<style>` tag.

You will get this:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This will change color over whole app (alerts, calendars, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

***you can follow the given link
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28502#issuecomment-702216228

or follow the the code comment below

***

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
     <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>  
</style>

  <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Open android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

and add   <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>   and 

 <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
</style>

and rebuild your app again. it will work fine. worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

You can use this library [React-Native_DropDown-Alert](https://github.com/testshallpass/react-native-dropdownalert). Its highly customizable library with predefined styles for differnet types of alerts. The code would go like this.

```
    <View>
          // !!! Make sure it's the last component in your document tree.
          <DropdownAlert
            ref={(ref) => this.dropdown = ref}
            onClose={(data) => this.onClose(data)} />
        </View>

// ...
handleRequestCallback(err, response) {
  if (err != null) {
    this.dropdown.alertWithType('error', 'Error', err)
  }
}
// ...
onClose(data) {
  // data = {type, title, message, action}
  // action means how the alert was dismissed. returns: automatic, programmatic, tap, pan or cancel
}
// ...
```