# How to change react native ios alert button color

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

So i want to use alert. My theme color is mainly black and yellow. For some reason the alert button in iOS also using yellow color like the one in image.

Is there a way for me to change the button clor to other color? for example black?

React Native 0.61

[image]

Comment: Maybe check the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666119/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-my-alert-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customize the default alert which react native provides because they are internally using native alert for both *android* and *ios* devices.

> For your requiement you have to use use [React Native Modalbox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal), or
>   [React Native Modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal) - both of which provide a highly-customisable
>   modal component.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom dialog for app using modal view
You can follow this link, it can help to implement custom dialog.

https://reactnativecode.com/create-custom-alert-dialog-box/

It's help me, use this.