# How do i change the font of my alert in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can fix fontSize and won't change because of system settings,
For the Text and Input I Used `allowFontScaling: false`,
For the WebView Used `textZoom={100}`
But for Alert what can Do?

```
Alert.alert(
  "Alert Title",
  "My Alert Msg",
  [
    {text: 'Ok', onPress: () => console.log('Ok Pressed')},
    {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed')},
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `Alert` and `AlertIOS` utilise each platform's native simple alert dialog. On iOS the underlying native component is simplistic and only accepts a title, message, and buttons, with a similar case on Android.

For a more custom approach you could use [React Native Modalbox](https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox), or  [React Native Modal](https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-modal) - both of which provide a highly-customisable modal component.

More details here [Link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665902/how-do-i-style-an-alert-element-in-react-native) and [Link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535263/custom-alert-dialog-in-react-native)

Comment: Your answer is a word for word copy of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535263/custom-alert-dialog-in-react-native 

Please don't copy answers, either mark as a duplicate or add a comment with a link to the answer

Comment: @Andrew got i, didn't find duplicate option so attached the ref link too